# Clojure printing lazy sequence

Tags: clojure, lazy-sequences

I'm trying to print out my binary tree but Clojure is giving me a hard time printing out the sequences properly.

So, I have a list of nodes `'(1 2 3)` for example.

In each iteration I want to print out the node with a number of spaces before and after each element.

```
(defn spaces [n]
  (apply str (repeat n " ")))
```

Great, this seems to work.

So, suppose I have a list of `nodes` `'(:a :b :c)` I want to print out on one line, with as said, the spaces.

```
(println (map #(str (spaces before) % (spaces (dec before))) nodes))
```

I have a list of items. Using the map I get a list of string objects. Great, so I can print them!

But this gives me this:

```
(clojure.lang.LazySeq@d0b37c31 clojure.lang.LazySeq@105879a9 clojure.lang.LazySeq@8de18242)
```

So I googled how to print lazy sequences and I came around to using `print-str` command. According to the docs this prints to a string which then gets returned.

```
(println (print-str (map #(str (spaces before) % (spaces (dec before))) nodes)))
```

But this gives me this:

```
(clojure.lang.LazySeq@d0b37c31 clojure.lang.LazySeq@105879a9 clojure.lang.LazySeq@8de18242)
```

No change.. Hrm. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
user> (str (map inc (range 10)))
"clojure.lang.LazySeq@c5d38b66"
user> (pr-str (map inc (range 10)))
"(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)"
```

The `toString` method of `LazySeq` is called by `str`, and this avoids realizing the lazy sequence of values by opaquely showing the Object identity. The `pr-str` function calls the `print-dup` multimethod of an object, which is designed to get the version of a thing that could be understood by the reader (so for a `LazySeq` the literal value that would make an equal `LazySeq`).

For pretty formatting of structures, do check out the `clojure.pprint` namespace which comes with `clojure.core`, which has `pprint`, `print-table`, and various functions for customizing the behavior of pretty printing.

```
user> (require '[clojure.pprint :as pprint :refer [pprint print-table]])
nil
user> (pprint [:a [:b :c :d [:e :f :g] :h :i :j :k] :l :m :n :o :p :q [:r :s :t :u :v] [:w [:x :y :z]]])
[:a
 [:b :c :d [:e :f :g] :h :i :j :k]
 :l
 :m
 :n
 :o
 :p
 :q
 [:r :s :t :u :v]
 [:w [:x :y :z]]]
nil
user> (print-table (map #(let [start (rand-int 1e6)] (zipmap % (range start (+ start 10)))) (repeat 5 [:a :b :c :d :e :f :g :h :i :j])))

|     :a |     :c |     :b |     :f |     :g |     :d |     :e |     :j |     :i |     :h |
|--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------|
| 311650 | 311652 | 311651 | 311655 | 311656 | 311653 | 311654 | 311659 | 311658 | 311657 |
|  67627 |  67629 |  67628 |  67632 |  67633 |  67630 |  67631 |  67636 |  67635 |  67634 |
| 601726 | 601728 | 601727 | 601731 | 601732 | 601729 | 601730 | 601735 | 601734 | 601733 |
| 384887 | 384889 | 384888 | 384892 | 384893 | 384890 | 384891 | 384896 | 384895 | 384894 |
| 353946 | 353948 | 353947 | 353951 | 353952 | 353949 | 353950 | 353955 | 353954 | 353953 |
nil
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to me that `str` avoids realizing the lazy sequence:
`user> (str (map #(do (println %) (inc %)) (range 10)))`
results in
`0  
1  
2  
3  
4  
5  
6  
7  
8  
9  
"clojure.lang.LazySeq@c5d38b66"`