# Why is this lazy-sequence not printing?

Tags: clojure, lazy-sequences, cons, take

I cannot figure out why this lazy-sequence is not printing. I've looked at other posts on here (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23405852/clojure-printing-lazy-sequence)) and none seem to be exactly what I am looking for. Here is the code segment...

```
(defn exp [x n]
    (reduce * (repeat n x))
)

(defn primes
    ([] (primes 1 1))
    ([n m] (if (= n 1) (lazy-seq (cons (* (exp 7 n) (exp 11 m)) (primes (+ m 1) (1))))
        (lazy-seq (cons (* (exp 7 n) (exp 11 m)) (primes (- n 1) (+ m 1)))))
    )
)

(take 4 (primes))
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You don't have `print` anywhere, that's why it's not printed.

Comment: Because it's lazy! ;)

Comment: `(1)` is an error. You don't mean to call 1 as a function.

Comment: What do you want it to print?

Answer (score 2):

The three comments really give the answer. But always good to actually see the code, so here are two ways that give the printed output.

```
(defn exp [x n]
  (reduce * (repeat n x)))

(defn primes
  ([] (primes 1 1))
  ([n m] (if (= n 1)
           (lazy-seq (cons (* (exp 7 n) (exp 11 m)) (primes (+ m 1) 1)))
           (lazy-seq (cons (* (exp 7 n) (exp 11 m)) (primes (- n 1) (+ m 1)))))))

(defn x-1 []
  (doseq [prime (take 4 (primes 2 2))]
    (println prime)))

(defn x-2 []
  (->> (primes 2 2)
       (take 4)
       (apply println)))
```